# Embedding SVG in PDF using Wicked_PDF (wkhtmltopdf)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, barcode, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

When I try to include an SVG in a PDF generated by wicked_pdf (wkhtmltopdf), it comes out blank. Any idea how to get the svg to display in the pdf?

**app/views/barcodes/to_pdf.html.haml**

```
<descriptive text here>
%object#code_image{:data=>"/barcodes/generate_svg?code=4567898", :type=>"image/svg+xml", :height=>70}
```

**barcodes controller**

```
def generate_svg
  require 'barby'
  require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
  require 'barby/outputter/svg_outputter'
  barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(params[:code])
  render :text => barcode.to_svg({:height=>30, :width => 170})
end


def to_pdf
 render :pdf        => 'file_name'      
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I got it to work using this method of embedding SVG.

[Display Inline SVG Using the  Tag](http://depth-first.com/articles/2011/10/19/display-inline-svg-using-the-img-tag/)

Replace

```
"data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVy..."
```

with

```
"data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{Base64.encode64(barcode.to_svg)}"
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how i adapted user1632065 answer to work in both html and pdf

in your GemFile

```
gem 'cairo'
gem 'barby'
```

in your model

```
class ExampleModel
  def barcode
    require 'barby'
    require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
    require 'barby/outputter/cairo_outputter'
    Barby::CairoOutputter.new(Barby::Code128B.new('bla bla this is barcode source'))
  end
end
```

in your view(in my case haml)

```
%img{:width => ExampleModelObject.barcode.width, :src=> "data:image/svg+xml;base64,#{Base64.encode64(ExampleModelObject.barcode.to_svg)}"}
```

this way you get correct barcode width

Answer (score 1):

I use wicked_pdf in one of my Rails 3.0.x app and it works like a charm. I use SVG code embedded directly into HTML (erb/haml views). No  or  - just pure  tag with given 'width' and 'height' attributes. It does not work for some browsers (Opera, IE<9), but I don't care about that in my case. Maybe you could try going with your stuff that way?