# Html to Pdf gem

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, svg, rubygems

I have a view that contains html with embedded svg and what I want to do is make the user able to save the view as a pdf file on their local machine so I need a gem that converts from html that has embedded svg code to pdf. Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/pdf_generation

Comment: You'll probably want to look at the following stackoverflow question - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880079/embedding-svg-in-pdf-using-wicked-pdf-wkhtmltopdf` which should hopefully be of some use. With regards to the whole conversion of HTML > PDF you will be best of using wicked_pdf. Awesome gem!